# ImageAssemble and Export gif takes too much memory

Tags: export, memory, image

Errr....
First Let's create some gifs:

```
dir = CreateDirectory@"D:\\lalala\\img_test";
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {8, 100}];
i = 0; (i++; 
Export[FileNameJoin[{dir, ToString@i <> "r.gif"}], ListLinePlot@#, 
ImageResolution -> 160]) & /@ data
```

so we have 8 *r.gif now(*character 'r' is used for easy "r.gif"s string match later *), MaxMemoryUsed[] gives 54874752, it seems fine, then ImageAssemble these *r.gif:

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{dir, "all.gif"}], 
ImageAssemble[
Partition[Import /@ FileNames["*r.gif", dir], 2] /. 
x_Image :> ImageCrop[x, {800, 512}, Padding -> Automatic]], 
ImageResolution -> 160]
```

"all.gif" is successfully and correctly created, however, check for MaxMemoryUsed[] it gives 211305360!!!(*the {800, 512} in the code above is the max size of r.gifs in my PC *)

In my Win7 Mathematica9, the *r.gifs are around 35kB and finial  all.gif is 285kB, How should ImageAssemble and Export take more than 200M memory to do this? In real problem I have even larger and more gifs to deal with, and Mathematica crashed when I tryed to "combine" and export them. Is there any way to avoid this problem? or should I turn to other picture format?

Comment: are you sure this is not because you are adding way too many pixels in the cropping stage?

Comment: I'm sure, the amount of pixels added in the cropping stage is negligible compared to img itself.  @gpap, the biggest eaxmple-img is  {800, 510} in my computer.